# single form and multiple submit (with multiple value)

Tags: html, jquery, forms, asp.net-core, post

I Have a "For **Loop**" In ASP.NET Core Like This :

`<button type="submit" Form="FormActive" name="id" value="@item.I"></button>`

```
 <!--It Will Create SomeThing Like This:-->
 <button type="submit" Form="FormActive" name="id" value="1"></button>
 <button type="submit" Form="FormActive" name="id" value="2"></button>
 <button type="submit" Form="FormActive" name="id" value="3"></button>
  ...          ...               ...        ...           4
  ...          ...               ...        ...           99
<!--And This Is My Single Form : -->
    <form id="FormActive" action="/action_page">
</form>
```

Whats The Problem?
why This Form Just Send A **httpRequest POST** **Without"ID"** And Value?(infact It Will Send A Post Request With **Empty Body**)

What I Should To do for **send ID**

Edit: I cant **Remove Form** - And I Cant Use **+99 Form** too
maybe i need jquery ... or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about try `asp-action` , like

```
<form id="FormActive" asp-action="Index">
</form>
```

Then in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Index(int id)
 {
    
     return View();
 }
```

result:

[image]

**Update**:

Try to use `<a>` tag  without With Tag Form

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index2" asp-route-id="1"><button>1</button></a>
```

Then in controller;

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult Index2(int id)
  {
   return View();
   }
```

result:

[image]

**Update2**
We can add a hidden `<input>` in the form to get the id like:

```
<button type="submit" Form="FormActive" name="id" value="1">a</button>
<form id="FormActive"  method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="completed">    
    <input id="buttonid"  type="hidden" name="id" />        
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("button").click(function (e) {      
        var fired_button = $(this).val();
        alert(fired_button);
        $('#buttonid').val(fired_button);
    });
</script>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @YaSecu  , How about my update, if you Dont Want Create a Lopp With Tag Form.

Comment: Now Your Code Is Okey but not in my project... :( Because I have This Form : `<form id="FormActive"  asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Confirm"
data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-confirm="Sure?"
data-ajax-failure="OnFailMethod" data-ajax-success="OnSuccMethod"></form>`  So I Cant Remove Form and use link

Comment: @YaSecu  With id parameter in the action ,and your code provided can get the id value. No need to Create +99 <Form></Form> . You can have a try.

Comment: Yes Bro ... I know now **dont need +99Form** ... But  Now Your Code have **0 form**... I Know It Work I Can See it ...  but I need **one Form** and Cant Remove Form Because  my Form Is Not just the sender of the post request ... u know

Comment: Hi @YaSecu , "Your Code have 0 form" I mean with your code in the question  with id parameter in the action  can get  one id value. If I understand you correctly, do you mean you want to get the all button value like a list and with the form when you submit the form ? Or?

Comment: no no noo bro... My Mean Now Your Code Is Fine... But I cant Do That ... Because All Of My Project Have Ajax(for return result and ...) And This Project Are not Short ... Now **What I want ?** : i have one page that **show All Products** for ADMIN --> Now IF Admin want Remove product he should **Click on Button** --> problem is here : Button Should **Send "ID" to my form** --> next form do **something(javascript-ajax result) and send post Request** --- I cant Remove Form

Comment: Because the backend is only related to the **form** and cant work with  `<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index2" asp-route-id="1">` ... -->
my form not just send request post It use ajax it show alert and ... and form is in _layout And it is not accessible Except for minor changes

Comment: Hi @YaSecu  , how about add a hidden input in the form to get the button id like update2?

Comment: oh my god it workkkk ... realy thank you for **your time** bro thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use input tag with type="submit" name="id" value="1"
Buttons does not have name and value attributes.

Comment: `<input type="submit"  form="FormActive" name="id" value="1"/> ` it dont send ID again--> Just Send A Request Post Without Body